# How does one "attach" code to an embedded technology?(say, attach a calculator program to a calculator.)

Tags: c++, c, embedded, system

This may sound a bit odd, but i always wondered myself. How does the software go into the hardware? I mean, sure, i can create a C or C++ program that does this, and ive done it before. But if i have a calculator, how does it work? How does the Manuf. "embed" the code into the machine? 
I know this is kinda off-topic, but this question has been haunting me for a long time.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's no different than your PC, which executes its first instruction off of a piece of flash.

Answer (score 3):

The typical solution for "single purpose" computers is to have some kind of Read Only Memory (ROM) that holds the code, and some RAM that holds temporary data such as the current values being calculated and small programs that a programmable calculator may allow.

The old school method was "masked ROM", where transistors are placed to form zero and one values in accordance to what the memory content wanted is, which is great if you want to make a million ROM modules of exactly the same code.

Modern machines, however, often use FLASH memory, which is programmable and holds data permanently(kind of at least), but also reprogrammed. In between, there have been EPROM memory, that would hold the code, but can be erased and reprogrammed in a special programming device.

This is also how your mobile phone, PC or Mac gets started, since it has to have some way to "initialize" things to the point where the OS takes over - called "bootstrap" - in a PC, it's called a BIOS, "Basic Input Output System" or UEFI "Unified Extensible Firmware Interface".

In a 1990's PC, it was an EPROM with the BIOS. Today, it's a FLASH ROM.

Flash ROM memory is also used for SSD-drives, and in SD-cards that hold files for mobile phones and digital cameras. Same basic principle, but mass storage is subtly different.

Comment: thanks, quite insightful!